# mergesort 17 comparisons using 8 elements

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I was solving a problem and came across with this solution, create an ordering of the numbers 1 through 8 that will cause merge-sort to do the worst-case number of comparisons of 17.

`[7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 6, 2]` , I solved it and happened have 16 comparisons, according to the solution, it is 17 comparisons? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes 4 compares to create 4 sorted runs of size 2. The it takes 2 sets of 3 compares to create 2 sorted runs of size 4. Then it takes 7 compares to create 1 sorted run of size 8.

Comment: I got the first 2 (4 compares and 6 compares) correctly, but I am still unsure how you get 7 at the end, I ended up got 6. Mind elaborate more on that? I am using the counting inversions.

Comment: The last pass merges two sorted runs of size 4 each to create a single sorted run of 8. In the worst case, there's one compare for each element moved, except for the last remaining element which is just copied, so that's 7 compares.